# What counts as original content according to youtube's api?

Tags: fair-use, youtube

Suppose that a developer intends to develop an app capable of searching and recommending videos from youtube, courses from udemy and content from other sites. Is s/he allowed to have subscriptions and ads on such an app while using youtube's api? I understand it's allowed to use the api if the platform contains original content, but does content from other platforms count? If not, to what extent can the app be monetized, if at all?

Comment: You would have to consult the YouTube API terms of service. I looked briefly but did not see any definition or even any reference at all to "original content." It's possible it's implied by some other words, but you'd have to read it in detail.

Comment: When I was trying to find an answer to my question, I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148606/is-it-legal-to-use-youtube-data-api-to-create-youtube-like-app-that-aggregrate-y. Now that i'm looking at the TOS it seems it's been changed to allow commercial use, unless they moved that section to somewhere else.